# removing value from userdefault is not working :: Issue with userdefault

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

To store value in UserDefaults, i am doing `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn")`

To remove value from UserDefaults, i am doing `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn")`

removeObject is not working.

I have tried below ways:

1. `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(nil, forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn")`
2. Tried by executing in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

To generate this issue, -> Delete derived data -> Fresh Install app, after successful login, store value and remove. -> Install the app again, it will work fine -> Uninstall and install again. -> Login the app and logout -> Reinstall from Xcode and check at AppDelegate, value is not removed even after logging out.

NOTE: I am having machine with M1 chip, can this matter for this issue?

Comment: First of all never use `setValue(forKey` in `UserDefaults`, you don't need KVC to store a `Bool`. As the type is a `Bool` anyway why not simply `UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn")` to reset the value because `false` is returned if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify in your question how you are accessing the value for `"kIsUserLoggedIn"` after removal of this value.

```
// Value is removed from storage
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn")

// prints `nil` as there's nothing stored for this key anymore
print(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn"))
```

All fine up to now, in case you are using [`UserDefaults.bool(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416388-bool) api, it will rightfully print `false`.

```
// prints `false`
print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "kIsUserLoggedIn"))
```

> The Boolean value associated with the specified key. **If the specified key doesn‘t exist, this method returns `false`.**
>
> This method automatically coerces certain ”truthy” values—such as the strings "true", "YES", and "1", and the numbers 1 and 1.0—to the Boolean value true. The same is true for certain ”falsy” values—such as the strings "false", "NO", and "0", and the numbers 0 and 0.0—which are automatically coerced to the Boolean value false.

---

As @vadian mentioned above, you shouldn't need to remove the value for this key from defaults entirely. You can set this to `false` and then work with the `Bool` directly in all cases instead of the way you are trying currently.

---

Here's a simple example of how to use a `Bool` value stored in `UserDefaults`.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    var isUserLoggedIn: Bool {
        get { self.bool(forKey: #function) }
        set { self.setValue(newValue, forKey: #function) }
    }
}

// Usage
UserDefaults.standard.isUserLoggedIn = true // upon log in
UserDefaults.standard.isUserLoggedIn = false // upon log out

// when app launches
if UserDefaults.standard.isUserLoggedIn {
   // user is logged in
}
```

Comment: Here, issue is not about way or methodology to store and retrieve value, 
i have given steps in question to generate issue where i am getting value even after removing value or reseting userdefault key.

Comment: BTW, i have tried the way you explain to store and get value, but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

To storing and removing boolean value inside Userdefault you can create your own extension shown below:-

extension UserDefaults {

```
//MARK:- Store bool value in Userdefault
public class func bool(forKey: String) -> Bool {
 
     let boolValue = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: forKey)
     return boolValue
    
}

/**
 removes object from NSUserDefault stored for a given key
 
 - parameter defaultName: key for object
 */
class func removeObjectForKey(_ defaultName: String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: defaultName)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

}

Comment: Here, issue is not about way or methodology to store and retrieve value, i have given steps in question to generate issue where i am getting value even after removing value or reseting userdefault key.
BTW, i have tried your way to get and store value in defaults but didnt work.